# How do I restrict access to a website hosted on an Azure VM to a given IP and itself?

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis

I am doing some testing on an Azure VM and have an ASP.NET website that I wish to limit access to. The website should only be accessible from a given IP (our office) but I also want the server to be able to make requests to other websites hosted on itself.

I have successfully setup an IP and Domain Restriction for our office IP but cannot find a way to allow requests internally from itself.

Is this possible without setting up a static IP in Azure?

Comment: You should be posting this to ServerFault, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

This question should be migrated to ServerFault, but given that there are programmatic approaches to it, I'll answer:

You need to set up Access Control Lists on the input endpoints, to specify ranges (via CIDR notation) of allowable or blocked IP addresses.

While this may be done via the portal, you may do it via the CLI:

`azure vm endpoint acl-rule create [vm-name] [endpoint-name] [order] [action] [remote-subnet]`

You may do this via PowerShell as well. Rough outline:

- Use `New-AzureAclConfig` to set up a config object
- Use `Set-AzureAclConfig` to add rules to the config
- Use `Get-AzureVM` to retrieve the config of your given virtual machine and add the ACL config to the VM
- Use `Update-AzureVM` to save your changes

More PowerShell details [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-acl-powershell/).